# Why did the synchronizing task in Apache IoTDB Version 1.1 has no effect when using `**` in select and root?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to ask about data synchronization in Apache IoTDB Version 1.1, and I already checked the official guide. If my SQL is written as `select ** from root.**`, IoTDB should not crash, right? Since the official guide states that when creating synchronizing task, `select` statement can support `**`. Then why did the task has no effect even though I configured the synchronization task and started it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `flush` and recheck Apache IoTDB system. If the data synchronization task still doesn't't work, you can try to update your version to 1.2.2 and above, and see if you can use data synchronization of that version, since data synchronization before Version 1.2 will not be under maintenance.